# Failed to instantiate module formlyBootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-formly

I've installed `angular-formly-templates-bootstrap` via bower on a project that I've been working on. But when I try to inject it in angular, I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bandar due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module formlyBootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'formlyBootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/nomod?p0=formlyBootstrap
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1949:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1873:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1947:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4355:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4339:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4356:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:336:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4339:5)
```

The problem is, bower doesn't load `angular-formly-templates-bootstrap` in the browser. There are some other packages which are being loaded to the browser with bower. But I don't know what the problem is with `formlyBootstrap`.

Comment: Angular can't find the module so it looks like you've either not defined it, not defined it correctly or you've not loaded it in you HTML page.

Comment: I added some extra explanations. I hope it helps... @MattHerbstritt

Comment: those templates don't work properly with bower without reconfiguring them yourself

Comment: @charlietfl I couldn't find something about reconfiguring it, in its documantation. Are there any documents exlpaining the correct way to do it?!

Comment: Are you certain that you've included the `angular-formly-templates-bootstrap` script on the page? This is what all [the examples](http://angular-formly.com) are doing. Also, make certain that you include it before your custom scripts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using gulp for inject bower dependencies? If so, find in gulp config something like that

```
exports.wiredep = {
  exclude: [/bootstrap.js$/, /bootstrap-sass-official\/.*\.js/, /bootstrap\.css/],
  directory: 'bower_components'
};
```

So all files ended with 'bootstrap.js' not injected. You can chage it with  something like that

```
exports.wiredep = {
  exclude: [/[^-]bootstrap.js$/, /bootstrap-sass-official\/.*\.js/, /bootstrap\.css/],
  directory: 'bower_components'
};
```

Comment: Wish I could just give you more of my points. This solution just saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error. I was working with gulp angular generator which seems to be ignoring formly bootstrap. I changed the main file in bower_components for angular-formly-bootstrap-template to dist/...bootstrap.min.js. Started working after that. Seems like the generator was ignoring files having bootstrap.js at the end